# LimeSurvey - Render questions groups by group_order, then questions by question_order

Tags: limesurvey

Is it possible to display or render an assessment to the user with its questions ordered by group_order and then its questions ordered by question_order?

I've been trying to achieve this without any luck for the last two days. Structure ordering doesn't match with what is actually been displayed to the user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to order them manually through the "organize" button?

https://manual.limesurvey.org/Survey_structure#Reordering_questions_and_question_groups

> > >
> >     In LimeSurvey 2, you have to click on the Survey button to access the home page of the survey and select the Question organizer option. 
> >     >